# How to prevent the release pipeline in VSTS from creating nuget.org packages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I created a build and release pipeline for my NuGet package using VSTS.

But after running the build and release pipeline successfully, the feed includes the nuget.org reference which was added. How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: The package source is "nuget.org". That means it's being pulled from nuget.org and cached in your package management instance. What's the problem with this behavior?

Comment: This is usually the desired behavior.

Comment: @ Daniel.@Paul  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. You enabled upstream sources and installed these packages through this feed. Refer to this documentation for details: [Saving packages from upstream sources: continuity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=vsts#saving-packages-from-upstream-sources-continuity).

> When you enable an upstream source, packages installed from the
>   upstream source via the feed will automatically be saved in the feed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried after removing the upstream options. But now the other refrences are coming from my project. I know it is by design. But is there a way to show only the package from my feed(my project package) and not include the other references?